# Python - How to get list from cluster plot chart?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn to use K-Mean clustering method. But the problem is I can retrieve lists from cluster plot chart. My code is like below

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
clusters = kmeans.fit(existing_df)

existing_df_2d['cluster'] = pd.Series(clusters.labels_, index=existing_df_2d.index)

existing_df_2d.plot(
        kind='scatter',
        x='PC2',y='PC1',
        c=existing_df_2d.cluster.astype(np.float), 
        figsize=(16,8))
```

[image]

Actually I already got the code how to get all the lists but in R programming language.

```
existing_df$cluster <- existing_clustering$cluster
table(existing_df$cluster)

//first cluster 
rownames(subset(existing_df, cluster==1))
existing_clustering$centers[1,]

//second cluster 
rownames(subset(existing_df, cluster==2))
existing_clustering$centers[2,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `existing_df_2d['cluster'].to_dict()`